# Change font size in Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android Cursor Modifier?

Tags: xamarin, charts, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, scichart

I have charts with 15-17 lines and the cursor modifier cuts off the view at 6 on phones. It looks great on tablets, but on phones, as said, only shows six. Is there a way to decrease the text size in the modifier to fit more lines?

Comment: Since this is a public website, for any programming questions, you're gonna have to tell the community what chart component you are using, maybe a code sample, a screenshot, that sort of thing. Otherwise the community will downvote you until you're unable to use the website

Answer (score 1):

As for Android I would suggest to take a look on [Custom Cursors example](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-chart-custom-cursors-example/) and use it as a base. In this example CustomXySeriesTooltip inherits from TextView which is used to render tooltip's text. So you can set font size for it like on regular TextView ( in ctor or internalUpdate override ):

```
public CustomXySeriesTooltip(Context context, XySeriesInfo seriesInfo) {
    super(context, seriesInfo);

    this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
}
```

And the code for Xamarin.Android should be similar to Java one.

---

As for iOS - you can use dataStyle property provided by [SCICursorModifierStyle](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/v2.x/api/interface_s_c_i_cursor_modifier.html#a58baa0aa39608fd29b7c036c1e24ca0f) which allows to specify font size:

```
SCITextFormattingStyle * textFormatting = [SCITextFormattingStyle new];
textFormatting.fontSize = 16;
textFormatting.fontName = @"Helvetica";

cursor.style.dataStyle = textFormatting;
```

Or you can create custom modifier like in [this example](https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-customization-cursor-modifier/).